# Is it a foul in football if the pursuer unintentionally clips the runner from behind?

Tags: rules, football

When I play recreational football, I pursue my man or a player a lot.  Sometimes, out of nowhere, their back foot clip my thigh while running and they trip.  It looks bad from far away and a foul is taken. I haven't done much besides running behind them or a bit on the side.

In another case, I was standing still and when the player twist and run, the same thing happen.

Is an unintentional clipping from behind considered as a foul in football?

Comment: wth? you're asking 2 questions here, one about football, and one about ultimate. The rules are going to be completely different for the two sports. Please split this question.

Comment: @waxeagle - I agree.  I've edited the question to remove the ultimate aspects.  The OP can ask a new question if he wants an answer regarding ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a short answer, but "Yes".

If you impede a player unfairly then your team will be penalised with the appropriate free-kick/penalty and possible card.

It doesn't matter if it's accidental or not, you have still impeded the player.

Law 12 (Misconduct) of the [Laws of the Game](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/generic/81/42/36/lawsofthegame_2011_12_en.pdf) state:

> A direct free kick is awarded to the opposing team if a player commits any
>   of the following seven offences in a manner considered by the referee to be
>   careless, reckless or using excessive force:
>
> [..]
>
> - trips or attempts to trip an opponent

The key word here is "careless".  When running behind a player you need to take care that you don't trip him.  If you do, you will be penalised with a direct free-kick against your team.

Comment: Plus it's often a cynical way of stopping a player who's got past a defender.